# SpringBoot 2.5.0 For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module: jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

**This is now fixed with SpringBoot 2.5.1**

Small question about a warning I am receiving please.

After the release of 2.5.0 of SpringBoot, I just did a version bump from 2.4.x to 2.5.0, without any code change.

Suddenly, on application start up, I am getting

`kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder: For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath`

The thing is, my Springboot all is not a Kotlin app, it is a Java app.

It has nothing Kotlin.

Furthermore, I am not even doing any explicit JSON parsing.

May I ask how I can disable, resolve this warning please?

Comment: Make sure that you don't have `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib` or `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect` in your dependencies (within maven/gradle script)

Comment: A similar issue has been added to the 5.3.8 milestone. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26962

Comment: Thanks for posting this. The **accepted answer** should be "Fixed in Spring Boot 2.5.1" so people don't bother with workarounds, when they may easily solve the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a solution [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21040). The idea is to provide extra configuration for `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`. Sucks that a code change is required but there you have it.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: **Just upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.1 where this is resolved.**

---

Old answer below:

I managed to fix this for now by adding exclusions to my spring-boot-starter-security dependency which apparently defined this Kotlin dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens as builder checks if kotlin-runtime is present in classpath by simple:

```
if (KotlinDetector.isKotlinPresent())
```

So you should only to remove kotlin-runtime from your project dependencies tree. For example, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security has transitive dependency to org.jetbrains.kotlin.
Simple exclude that as:

```
exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Not sure what that syntax is but how to configure this in a pom.xml?

Comment: That's also easy in maven. Dependency tag always has mechanism to exclusion some transitive dependencies: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#how-to-use-dependency-exclusions

Comment: Yeah I fixed it for now, I also added an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67800687/144578